# Satisfiablity 2

Tags: algorithms, satisfiability

Im trying to work out whether the following clause is satisfiable:

```
{x, y},{x,¬y},{¬x, y},{¬x,¬y},{x, z},{x,¬z},{y, z},{y,¬z}
```

My basic understanding is to work this out, you must give each literal a true or false assignment to work out if each clause is satisfiable so:

x=1
y=1
z=1

```
{1,1}, {x,0}, {0,1}, {0,0}, {1,1}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,0}
```

Therefore the clause {x,y} and {x,z} are satisfiable?

I also heard you can switch the statement so:

x=1
y=0
z=1

This means {x,y} is not satisfiable.

If we changed z to 0 as well {x,z} would not be satisfiable. What really confuses me here is when the truth assignments are changed, neither clauses are satisfiable.

where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "clause" in "work out whether the following clause is satisfiable"? Do you want to satisfy each piece separately or perhaps the whole formula being the conjunction of the elements?

Comment: each clause as in the literals in each {} sorry for confusion.

Comment: There is yet one more confusing matter: there is a difference between "satisfiable" and "satisfied". The first means that it is _possible to satisfy_ the clause/formula (i.e. there exists a valuation such that the whole evaluates to $\mathtt{true}$), while "satisfied" describes whether the formula evaluates to $\mathtt{true}$ with regard to a particular valuation. For example ${x,y}$ is satisfiable, but for $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ it is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No. It is not satisfiable**.

You can see this by focusing on a subset of the clauses. In particular:
$$\{x, y\},\{x,¬y\},\{¬x, y\},\{¬x,¬y\}$$
Think of them as ordered pairs,
$$(x, y),(x,¬y),(¬x, y),(¬x,¬y)$$
Notice that we have all $4$ possible clauses which can be formed from $x$ and $y$.
Also, since they are all distinct clauses, any assignment of $0$ or $1$ to $x$ and $y$ will give distinct values for the $4$ ordered pairs.

Since there are $4$ possible ordered pairs of $0$'s and $1$'s (and our clauses must evaluate to $4$ distinct pairs), any assignment must take on **all** values from the set,

$$\{(0, 0),(0,1),(1, 0),(1,1)\}$$

Hence we must have $(0,0)$

In particular, it is not satisfiable.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- You need to assign each variable $\mathtt{true}$ or $\mathtt{false}$ value, so that each clause is satisfied.
- The easiest way to do this for general $2$-CNF is to construct the [implication graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implication_graph). Each clause $\{\alpha, \beta\}$ gives you two implications $\neg \alpha \to \beta$ and $\neg \beta \to \alpha$, for example $\{x,\neg y\}$ would give you $\neg x \to \neg y$ and $y \to x$.
- The formula is satisfiable if and only if the implication graph contains no pair of paths $\alpha \to^* \neg \alpha$ and $\neg\alpha \to^* \alpha$ for some $\alpha$.
- In your particular case you can observe that the first four clauses are all the possible clauses of two variables, hence are not satisfiable together (for any valuation there will be a clause where the negations match exactly the $\mathtt{true}$'s).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$